# CheckBox в QHeaderView

Tags: qt, view, header, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

Как поместить QCheckBox в заголовок QTableWidget? Без отрисовке через примитивы

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вроде бы уже что-то сделано по этой теме:  
https://forum.qt.io/topic/127103/add-a-qcheckbox-as-a-header-to-a-qtablewidget  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557913/checkbox-in-a-header-cell-in-qtableview